# How to get SUM of certain column without losing all rows?

Tags: mysql, select, sum

```
CREATE TABLE tmp ( col1 int, col2 int );
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (1,3), (2,5), (3,7);

SELECT col1, col2, SUM(col2) AS Total FROM tmp; -- ???
```

The `SELECT` statement leaves me with this data set:

col1     col2     Total
  1         3          15

Is there a way to allow all the rows to appear without introducing a subquery, so that the result is this:

col1     col2     Total
  1         3          15
  2         5          15
  3         7          15

Comment: With a temporary table? No.

Comment: SELECT x.*, SUM(y.col2) FROM tmp x, tmp y GROUP BY x.col1;

Comment: @JohnBollinger From what to what?

Comment: @Strawberry, I take it back.  your solution works, at the expense of computing a cross join.

Comment: @Strawberry post it as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks

Comment: Why *"without a subquery"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cross join to avoid a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, sum(t2.col2) sum_col2
from tmp t1
cross join tmp t2 
group by 1, 2
```

See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dca1e/1)

Note that this only works if combinations of col1 and col2 are unique.